# Asking for "Requests for Comments"

Tags: discussion, not-a-real-question

I'm currently writing a set of tutorials on advanced OpenGL topics. Stuff that's in the intermediary level and would like to get some feedback on them.

SO is about asking programming questions to solve someone's problem, but I wonder if it was acceptable to ask for comments on the tutorials on SO, or some meta or another SE site. I'm still a Usenet fan, and `c.g.a.opengl` is used for announcements, requests for help etc. Unfortunately (*sigh* ATM c.g.a.opengl gets severely spam-trolled) it lacks a voting system.

So how do you deal with things not a question in the first place here?

Comment: +1 for asking before doing

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ was made for this, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as series of questions + answers.

Ask a **very good** hypothetical question, then provide the relevant part of your tutorial as an answer.